# DataStax OpsCenter 3.2.2 fails to start properly when storing collection data on different server

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to run OpsCenter 3.2.2 (enterprise edition) using a separate cluster used for storing the collection data. I specify the [storage_cassandra] tag in the cluster configuration. When starting opscenter, the log shows the following:

> 2013-10-31 10:21:52+0000 [YarinCluster1]  INFO: Created keyspace OC_cluster1
>   2013-10-31 10:21:52+0000 [YarinCluster1] ERROR: Error when attempting to create OpsCenter schema: (AttributeError) Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/ClusterServices.py", line 378, in _createSchema
>       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keyspaces'
>
> 2013-10-31 10:21:52+0000 [YarinCluster1]  INFO: Sleeping for 10s before retrying schema creation

I cut out a lot of log lines before this. The weird thing is that it actually manages to create the keyspace (which I named OC_cluster1) with all the column families, but immediately after something fails. It will keep on retrying every 10 seconds, but always fail.

If I go into OpsCenter, most things seem to work except that Alerts can't be loaded ('Error loading alerts: Alerts have not been loaded yet. There may be a connectivity problem with Cassandra.')

If I don't specify the [storage_cassandra] tag and store the collection data in the same cluster as the one I'm monitoring, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that is fixed with the next release, which is due out soon.

(I'm on the team)